# Am I using the class wrong?

Tags: php, class, mp3

I am trying to use this [class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/26606.html) to extract the first 30 seconds for a preview. Here is my code

```
include("class.mp3.php");
$file_input = "hat.mp3";
$file_output = "output.mp3";
$mp3 = new mp3($file_input); 
$mp3_1 = $mp3->cut_mp3($file_input, $file_output, 0, 30);
```

hat.mp3 is in the same directory and I was expecting to see output.mp3 as the 30 second clip...any ideas what i am doing wrong of if there is an easier and better library to use for this case....

Comment: What are you  getting instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cut_mp3` function and other function `get_mp3` etc uses '@' operator:

```
 if(!$fp = @fopen($file_output, 'wb')) {
    return false;
 }
```

And you will not see any error message. First of all check permission to directory.

Comment: what do you mean the @ operator....u mean like @cut_mp3 as in this $mp3_1 = $mp3->@cut_mp3($file_input, $file_output, 0, 30);

Comment: Yes, and with this operator you will not see any error messages. Because of this you should check permission manually.

Answer (score 1):

The Web server needs to have write permissions for the directory where you want to output your MP3. Unfortunately the class doesn't seem to have any error-handling for when it can't write the output MP3.